# Naming column with conditions

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, impala

I have a table like [this](https://s22.postimg.org/sy24l6vld/casewhen.jpg):
My task is to prepare a query for listing KPIs and calculations for them.

1) First I tried the case when statement like this(shortened):

```
select case  
        When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_STATS_TYPE = 3 THEN "S11 Session Successes"
        When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_STATS_TYPE = 3 AND (CAUSE_CODE is NULL OR CAUSE_CATEGORY="S") THEN "S11 Update Successes"  
        When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_STATS_TYPE = 7 THEN "Modify Access Bearer Successes"   
    End kpi_name, Sum(count) cnt
```

This brought me two problems:
1) the case-when statement stops when it meets the first condition, so it would succesfully determine and label the row as *"S11 Session Successs"* but it would not recognize the *"S11 Update Sucesses"* unless I make a union and write that in another select.

2) If there are no rows with relevant conditions, the results would not display the KPI name at all. 
I would prefer having the row displayed with KPI name and null or 0 value. I was trying to achieve this using the if statement, but I found nesting more and more condidtions into one big if statement is rather nasty and not easily modifiable.

Is there any more elegant way of achieving these 2 that Im missing? 
Thank you

EDIT:
To provide more information:
This query yields incorrect results:

```
select case
    --When S1AP_SGS_PROTOCOL_ID = 36412 AND S1AP_SGS_TRANS_TYPE = 16 AND ( S1AP_SGS_TRANS_CAUSE_VALUE is NULL OR CAUSE_CATEGORY="S")                    THEN     "HO Preparation Successes"
    When S1AP_SGS_PROTOCOL_ID = 36412 AND S1AP_SGS_TRANS_TYPE = 16    THEN     "HO Preparation Attempts"
    End kpi_name,                       
    Sum(trans_count) cnt

 From  s1mme_agg_start_time_2017022811                      
    where time >= "2017-02-28 11:00:00" and time < "2017-02-28 12:00:00"
    group by kpi_name
```

> HO Preparation Attempts    4560
>   HO Preparation Successes   28

While this query gives the correct results:

```
 select 
    When S1AP_SGS_PROTOCOL_ID = 36412 AND S1AP_SGS_TRANS_TYPE = 16 THEN "HO Preparation Attempts"
End kpi_name,                       
Sum(trans_count) cnt

From  s1mme_agg_start_time_2017022811                      
where time >= "2017-02-28 11:00:00" and time < "2017-02-28 12:00:00"
group by kpi_name

union

select case
    When S1AP_SGS_PROTOCOL_ID = 36412 AND S1AP_SGS_TRANS_TYPE = 16 AND ( S1AP_SGS_TRANS_CAUSE_VALUE is NULL OR CAUSE_CATEGORY="S")                    THEN     "HO Preparation Successes"

        End kpi_name,                       
    Sum(trans_count) cnt

From  s1mme_agg_start_time_2017022811                      
    where time >= "2017-02-28 11:00:00" and time < "2017-02-28 12:00:00"
    group by kpi_name
```

> HO Preparation Attempts    4588
>   HO Preparation Successes   28

Answer (score 0):

just check for the more selective when condition first and use else for manage no value

```
  select case
      When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_STATS_TYPE = 3 
              AND (CAUSE_CODE is NULL OR CAUSE_CATEGORY="S") THEN "S11 Update Successes"
      When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_STATS_TYPE = 3 THEN "S11 Session Successes"
      When PROTOCOLID = 61002 AND TRANS_STATS_TYPE = 7 THEN "Modify Access Bearer Successes"
      ELSE 'no value'
    End kpi_name
    , Sum(count) cnt
 .......
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but in impala this doesnt work for me. Ill put all the selective first but they are missing in the output unless I put them after the union clause.If I keep them in one select statement, the results will only display one of the case clauses

Comment: just did that, noticed other strange behaviour